# Why does Logcat not print a log when the tag starts with "IMS"?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Why does Logcat not print a log when the tag starts with "IMS"?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnOne:
            System.out.println("Button One log by sout");
            Log.e("IMSfsadfasdfasdf", "log by Log.e()");
            break;
        case R.id.btnTwo:
            System.out.println("Button Two log by sout");
            Log.e("MService", "log by Log.e()");
            break;
    }
}
```

Log:

```
04-07 15:05:48.838 4363-4363/com.licheedev.myapplication I/System.out: Button One log by sout
04-07 15:05:49.916 4363-4363/com.licheedev.myapplication I/System.out: Button Two log by sout
04-07 15:05:49.916 4363-4363/com.licheedev.myapplication E/MService: log by Log.e()
04-07 15:05:54.109 4363-4363/com.licheedev.myapplication I/System.out: Button Two log by sout
04-07 15:05:54.109 4363-4363/com.licheedev.myapplication E/MService: log by Log.e()
04-07 15:05:54.822 4363-4363/com.licheedev.myapplication I/System.out: Button One log by sout
04-07 15:05:55.638 4363-4363/com.licheedev.myapplication I/System.out: Button One log by sout
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That's weird. I tried in my app as well. Didn't print!

Comment: check your Log:Tag name ......... It should be same name as you mention in pic

Comment: Yeah, its strange. Its now showing in my app, too.

Comment: **Update** Tried with `Log.v/d/i/w` as well, it didn't print. And it is case sensitive, it prints "ims" and not "IMS".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure, but I think this have to do with this line of code in the log mechanism of Android. This is in the function `__android_log_write(prio, tag, buf);`

```
/* XXX: This needs to go! */
if (!strcmp(tag, "HTC_RIL") ||
    !strncmp(tag, "RIL", 3) || /* Any log tag with "RIL" as the prefix */
    !strncmp(tag, "IMS", 3) || /* Any log tag with "IMS" as the prefix */
    !strcmp(tag, "AT") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "GSM") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "STK") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "CDMA") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "PHONE") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "SMS")) {
        log_id = LOG_ID_RADIO;
        // Inform third party apps/ril/radio.. to use Rlog or RLOG
        snprintf(tmp_tag, sizeof(tmp_tag), "use-Rlog/RLOG-%s", tag);
        tag = tmp_tag;
}
```

Read [this blog](http://www.programering.com/a/MjNwcTNwATk.html) post for detailed information.

Comment: Very useful information. I have tried and none of tag is showing in Log which are listed in your answer. +1 for your answer.

Comment: Yes you're right, I tried with **RIL** and **AT**. It doesn't print. +1!

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interesting and funny at the same time: all those yahoo ads  :D